# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject C# object type without default constructor

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am getting a exception while deserializing my own custom class using JsonConvert.

Here is my custom class which I am using to return any data and error from Web Api. Note data is of type object.

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public object Data { get; private set; }

    public ResponseModel(bool isSuccess, string message, object data)
    {
        this.IsSuccess = isSuccess;
        this.Message = message;
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
```

Here is my Web Api Controller method.

```
public class CatalogApiController : ApiController
    {
        public ResponseModel GetAllCatalogs(string search, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            try
            {
                using(var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork<XXXX>())
                {
                    using (var catalogManager = new CatalogManager(unitOfWork))
                    {
                        var totalCount = 0;
                        var allProducts = catalogManager.GetAllSpecies(search, pageIndex, pageSize, out totalCount);
                        var paginatedList = new PaginatedList<Product>(allProducts, pageIndex, pageSize, totalCount);
                        return new ResponseModel(true, "", paginatedList);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO Handle Exception
                return new ResponseModel(false, "", null);
            }
        }
}
```

The PaginatedList class doesn't have a default constructor.

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalCount)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Source cannot be null.");
        }

        AddRange(source);

        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        TotalCount = totalCount;
    }
}
```

This is how I am converting converting the Json result back to ResponseModel.

```
            var allProductJson = //somehow get json result
            var allProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(allProductJson);
            if(allProduct.IsSuccess)
            {
                var productData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaginatedList<Product>>(allProduct.Data.ToString());//I am getting exception on this line.

            }
```

I am getting exception only if I use `PaginatedList<Product>`. If I return  `IList<Product>` from Web Api, I am not getting exception.

Exception Message:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type
>   XXXX.Business.Domain.PaginatedList`1[XXXX.Business.Domain.Product].
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.

Inner Exception:

> JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for
>   type
>   XXXX.Business.Domain.PaginatedList`1[XXXX.Business.Domain.Product].
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.]
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewList(JsonReader
>   reader, JsonArrayContract contract, Boolean&
>   createdFromNonDefaultCreator) +670
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   Object existingValue, String id) +198
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue) +238
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) +749
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType) +354
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type
>   objectType) +47
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings) +199
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings) +118
>
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value) +81
>
>   XXXX.Web.Controllers.HomeController.HomePage(String search, Nullable`1
>   page) in XXXX.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:50
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +225

Bonus Question:

1. How can I make ResponseModel Data Object strongly typed. I thought of using it as generic by making it as `ResponseeModel<T>`, but I have to make changes too many places. Is there is any way of getting strongly typed data form object using JsonConvert without having to parse it again(which I am doing in previous code).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates you need a default constructor then I suggest you add a default constructor. The deserializer needs to create an instance of a class it is rehydrating in a standardized way and so always expects a default constructor to be present. Once the instance is created it will try and set its state by setting public properties. You have defined 'private set' properties so I can not sure if it will manage to set them.

You then have the problem that you are trying to serialize/deserialize a class derived from List and I do not believe that List knows how to do so. So you will need to add custom serialization to the PaginatedList class.